# What to look for in a fisheye that is to be useful at multiple sensor formats?

Tags: full-frame, fisheye, aps-c

I am aware there are multiple projection types, and a complicated relationship between imaging circle, focal length and how a crop will look like.

How to choose a fisheye that is useful on a full frame camera as a circular, and useful as a semi-circular (or with some cropping, rectangular) on APS-C without just looking like a broken ultrawide?

Comment: Do you have sample images to illustrate "useful as a semi-circular" and "just looking like a broken ultrawide"?

Comment: My (mis?)understanding is that fisheyes are supposed to compress the corners in a certain "correct" way, depending on the type of fisheye... so won't I be cutting the good crust off the loaf cropping the wrong kind of fisheye?

Comment: True fisheyes don't really compress anything, corners or center. Rectilinear wide angle lenses *expand* corners.

Comment: So the classic fisheye projections are kind of fractal-like?

Comment: Classic fisheye projections are more or less the natural result of making a conventional lens with a very wide angle of view without altering the projection to make it rectilinear.

Comment: So even a perfectly corrected 35mm ff prime is technically distorting (in order to not be rectilinear) when used as a wideangle, while leaving it "natural" would make it an imperfect normal on APS-C?

Answer (score 1):

The usual routine for selecting lenses doesn't really change with the type of lens.

1. Read lens reviews.
2. Evaluate sample images.
3. Try out the lens yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Get the one that gives you the projection and angle of view that you want on APS-C. Using it on full frame will give you the same image in the center, with the additional vertical field of view, and whatever little additional horizontal the image circle provides.